# Is this log configuration correct?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-logging

I made a class of logs, to upload them to Gcp.
I understand that there are log handlers, which allow to show the logs locally and in Gcp.
I tried to upload this configuration from the logs, but the messages are repeated an absurd number of times and only with the error level. The truth is that I have tried a lot of configurations but nothing works for me.

```
import json
import logging

import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

from lib_logs.LogsConstantes import LogsConstantes


class LoggerPrinter:
    def __init__(self, negocio, uuid, canal, consumidor, log_name='cloudLogger', test=False):
        self.test = test
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.negocio = negocio
        self.canal = canal
        self.consumidor = consumidor

        if not self.test:
            self.glogging_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
            self.gcloud_logging_handler = CloudLoggingHandler(self.glogging_client, name=log_name)

        # Configurar el manejador de transmisión a la consola
        self.stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.stream_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Si no estás en un entorno de prueba, inicializa el cliente y el manejador de Google Cloud Logging
        if not self.test:
            self.logger.addHandler(self.gcloud_logging_handler)



    def _log(self, level, message, payload=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA, http_code=200,
             business_code=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA,
             process_type=LogsConstantes.PROCESO_DE_PROCESO):
        log_data = (
            f"UUID: {self.uuid}, "
            f"Negocio: {self.negocio}, "
            f"Canal: {self.canal}, "
            f"Consumidor: {self.consumidor}, "
            f"Message: {message}, "
            f"Payload: {payload}, "
            f"HTTPCode: {http_code}, "
            f"BusinessCode: {business_code}, "
            f"ProcessType: {process_type}"
        )
        log_message = json.dumps(log_data, ensure_ascii=False)
        log_method = getattr(self.logger, level)
        log_method(log_message)

    def debug(self, message, payload=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA, http_code=200,
              business_code=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA,
              process_type=LogsConstantes.PROCESO_DE_PROCESO):
        self._log('debug', message, payload, http_code, business_code, process_type)

    def info(self, message, payload=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA, http_code=200,
             business_code=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA,
             process_type=LogsConstantes.PROCESO_DE_PROCESO):
        self._log('info', message, payload, http_code, business_code, process_type)

    def warning(self, message, payload=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA, http_code=200,
                business_code=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA,
                process_type=LogsConstantes.PROCESO_DE_PROCESO):
        self._log('warning', message, payload, http_code, business_code, process_type)

    def error(self, message, payload=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA, http_code=200,
              business_code=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA,
              process_type=LogsConstantes.PROCESO_DE_PROCESO):
        self._log('error', message, payload, http_code, business_code, process_type)

    def critical(self, message, payload=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA, http_code=200,
                 business_code=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA,
                 process_type=LogsConstantes.PROCESO_DE_PROCESO):
        self._log('critical', message, payload, http_code, business_code, process_type)
```

This is the way I initialize it

```
import uuid

from flask import Flask, g, make_response, jsonify

from lib_logs import LoggerPrinter
from lib_logs.LogsConstantes import LogsConstantes

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.before_request
def set_uuid():
    g.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    g.logger_printer = LoggerPrinter(negocio="micro", uuid=g.uuid, canal="web", consumidor=LogsConstantes.VALOR_NA)


@app.route('/logs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    g.logger_printer.debug(message="Este es un mensaje de Debug")
    g.logger_printer.info(message="Este es un mensaje de Info")
    g.logger_printer.warning(message="Este es un mensaje de Warning")
    g.logger_printer.error(message="Este es un mensaje de Error")

    return make_response(jsonify({'liveness': 'True'}), 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I expect these messages without being repeated in the log console, including debug and info

`"UUID: 2e183715-9afa-4a02-903c-13af365d201c, Negocio: micro, Canal: web, Consumidor: Valor Na, Message: Este es un mensaje de Warning, Payload: Valor Na, HTTPCode: 200, BusinessCode: Valor Na, ProcessType: Proceso de proceso" "UUID: 2e183715-9afa-4a02-903c-13af365d201c, Negocio: micro, Canal: web, Consumidor: Valor Na, Message: Este es un mensaje de Error, Payload: Valor Na, HTTPCode: 200, BusinessCode: Valor Na, ProcessType: Proceso de proceso" 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2023 11:26:57] "POST /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -`